# Not getting a certificate chain from AndroidKeystore

Tags: android, certificate, keystore

I'm trying to verify a hardware-backed key using guidelines from https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation.html.

The key (ECDSA) is generated in the AndroidKeystore correctly, and KeyInfo provides the correct information for emulators:

```
Starting check for secure element
Generated an ECDSA key with 256 bits
Keyname: d512e563-92ea-4bfa-9e35-3043e5c55ae0
Key Imported?: Generated
Keysize: 256
UserAuth Required?: true
**In Secure HW?: false**
Finished check for secure element
```

and when I attempt to get the certificate chain, I get this:

```
  Found required key: d512e563-92ea-4bfa-9e35-3043e5c55ae0
    Number of certificates in chain: 1
    SubjectDN: CN=fake
    Serial Number: 1
    Issuer: CN=fake
    Valid from: Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969
    Valid Until: Tue Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 2047

    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIHFMIGxoAMCAQICAQEwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwDzENMAsGA1UEAxMEZmFrZTAeFw03
    MDAxMDEwMDAwMDBaFw00ODAxMDEwMDAwMDBaMA8xDTALBgNVBAMTBGZha2UwWTAT
    BgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAATZ/2iTrpOa35IAnhCiNU+UTfPukTMgvvdO
    gJyjQyDcu4+KjuJdesiqnw8bT1kmh4KO085Ri3ZFYKSloSU6GT1oMAoGCCqGSM49
    BAMCAwMAMAA=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

However, for real phones with a secure element, I get this:

```
Starting check for secure element
Generated an ECDSA key with 256 bits
Keyname: f416a3b1-a8a7-4aeb-b1d4-14a5cf459506
Key Imported?: Generated
Keysize: 256
UserAuth Required?: true
**In Secure HW?: true**
Finished check for secure element
```

and when I attempt to get the certificate chain, I get this:

```
Found required key: f416a3b1-a8a7-4aeb-b1d4-14a5cf459506
Number of certificates in chain: 1
SubjectDN: CN=fake
Serial Number: 1
Issuer: CN=fake
Valid from: Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969
Valid Until: Tue Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 2047

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIHFMIGxoAMCAQICAQEwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwDzENMAsGA1UEAxMEZmFrZTAeFw03
MDAxMDEwMDAwMDBaFw00ODAxMDEwMDAwMDBaMA8xDTALBgNVBAMTBGZha2UwWTAT
BgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAAQAwtqkhgodfwFGEOyEKEJSP2u+hdpLlZ1B
OIGFUeiZ0dZOHLvg6D4ivJ/j7xe0AvNp+TdnOdTtx7zKSAnfxD6bMAoGCCqGSM49
BAMCAwMAMAA=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I cannot seem to get the actual certificate chain no matter what emulator or real phone device I use.

The example on github for certificate chain verification assumes you already acquired the chain correctly and are using those certificates for validation; but I don't see any example of what code one must have to get the chain correctly. Here is what I have in my code:

```
try {
            keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_PROVIDER);
            keystore.load(null);
            Enumeration<String> keys = keystore.aliases();
            sb = new StringBuilder("Certificate chain of key in AndroidKeystore:\n\n");
            while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String s = keys.nextElement();
                Log.i("info", "KeyAlias: " + s);
                KeyStore.Entry entry = keystore.getEntry(keyalias, null);
                if (entry != null) {
                    Log.i("info", "Found required key: " + keyalias);
                    certchain = ((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getCertificateChain();
                    Log.i("info", "Number of certificates in chain: " + certchain.length);
                    return sb.append(getCertChain(certchain)).toString();
                }
            }
            Log.w("error", "Key not found: " + keyalias);
            sb.append(getResources().getString(R.string.key_not_found));
        } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | UnrecoverableEntryException | CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
```

(Please excuse formatting errors).

All devices are running API 24 or greater. What am I missing in trying to get the actual certificate chain for attestation?  TIA.

Answer (score 2):

When you created your keypair, did you call setAttestationChallenge()? If not, it will just generate your self-signed certificate.

Comment: Thank you. I did figure this out after some additional research and asking people - the clue came from a single line of code in Test cases used by the Android team to test for that capability. I've, unfortunately, been swamped with work to have come back to submit the answer to this question. However, I do hope to release some open-source code later this year that demonstrates the use of the AndroidKeystore for a lot of secure operations. Thanks for taking the time to respond to it.

Comment: https://github.com/vvb2060/KeyAttestation sample project